# OCR: Extracting Room Names from Floor Plans with Tesseract (Images Included)

Tags: python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, image-preprocessing

I'm reaching out for some friendly advice on a project using Tesseract to extract room names from floor plan images. I'm pretty confident my post-processing is on point, but I'm stuck on the tricky parts: pre-processing and model configuration.
My Workflow:

**Pre-processing**: I've tried grayscale conversion, resizing, and even some adaptive thresholding magic, but it seems like I'm missing something for consistent results.

**Model Config**: I'm using PyTesseract with the "Sparse text" (`psm 11`) config hoping to catch everything, but maybe that's not the best approach?

**Post-processing**: Filtering out clutter and matching names with a dictionary feels pretty good.

**Result**
Out of 50 test images, I get stellar results on 21 images (most room are detected).
[image]

**But then there are these quirky cases:**

Crystal clear plan, but only one lonely room detected. [image]

Accuracy also takes a dive here, and I suspect the culprit might be the colorful background. [image]

So, wise OCR gurus, I'm humbly asking for your insights! ‍♀️

Which pre-processing techniques should I befriend to tame these tricky images?
Is there a better Tesseract config hiding out there? I'm open to exploring different approaches!
Any general floor plan OCR wisdom would be gold.